# WCF Newbie: Create a WCF Proxy to connect to old ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asmx, soa

I am currently assigned on a task where I need to create a WCF that will act as a proxy to 3 ASMX services. Currently these services are consumed directly by several applications.

Reason for building this WCF proxy is that it would be easier for us to update the asmx certificates in just one point of entry (the WCF proxy service) rather than several applications.

I've created an ordinary .NET class library that basically creates a singleton instance for the ASMX service, but I'm not sure how I could expose it in a WCF service.

Would it be possible if you could point me out where I could see excamples of a WCF acting as a proxy for consuming ASMX services?

Below is my code:

```
public static class Service<T> where T : WebServicesClientProtocol
{
    static volatile T _Instance;
    static volatile int _NumberOfReference = 0;
    static object syncRoot = new object();

    static Service() { }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_Instance == null)
                    _Instance = ServiceProxyHelper.CreateServiceProxy<T>(ConfigValueHelper.GetServiceUrl(typeof(T).Name), ConfigValueHelper.CertificateHashKey);
                }
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the helpers that I use:

```
public static class ServiceProxyHelper
{
    public static T CreateServiceProxy<T>(string url, string clientBase64KeyId)
    {
        var webService = SetSecurityCredentials(clientBase64KeyId, url, typeof(T));

        if (webService == null)
            return default(T);

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(webService, typeof(T));
    }

    private static WebServicesClientProtocol SetSecurityCredentials(string clientBase64KeyId, string url, Type serviceType)
    {
        WebServicesClientProtocol result = null;

        result = (WebServicesClientProtocol)Activator.CreateInstance(serviceType, true);
        result.Url = url;

        //Verify default credentials
        if (WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy != null)
        {
            result.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            result.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            result.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        }

        //Add security credentials to SOAP envelope
        var token = ServiceProxyHelper.GetSecurityToken(clientBase64KeyId, url);

        if (token == null)
            return null;

        result.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
        result.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(token));

        return result;
    }

    private static X509SecurityToken GetSecurityToken(string clientBase64KeyId, string url)
    {
        X509SecurityToken result = null;
        X509Certificate x509Certificate = null;

        var store = X509CertificateStore.CurrentUserStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
        var isOpen = store.OpenRead();

        foreach (X509Certificate certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.GetKeyIdentifier()) != clientBase64KeyId)
                continue;

            x509Certificate = certificate;
            result = new X509SecurityToken(certificate);
            break;
        }

        if (isOpen)
            store.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you unable to change the existing asmx services ?  Why do you need a proxy vs. updating the services to WCF ?
Also - why do you think that you need a singleton instance ?

Comment: @markt: I'm consuming a 3rd party asmx web service, so we don't have control over it. At present, our apps are using a singleton instance when consuming the asmx directly, so I incorrectly assumed that it will be the same with WFC. We need the proxy for maintenance purpose because the 3rd party asmx use SSL certificates, and every year we have to update all apps that consume it. It will be tedious for us to update all apps that use it.

Comment: Ok - you mentioned that you have 3 services.  I would recommend against having a single proxy with methods for all services.. This is kind of like a god service that could potentially cause problems later if you ever need to have different access rules for each service...  unless all 3 services are *always* used by *all* clients. What if you have to phase one of them out.. do you want to break the contract for *all* clients ?  You could host your multiple service proxy enpoints within a single application, or rely on a common configuration file to solve your maintenance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this case i would create a [ServiceContract] in WCF and add all the methods from ASMX that i want the clients to access. Then expose that service contract using WCF endpoints. It would act like a facade. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for this Abdul. Follow-up question: Do I also still need to specify the DataContract attribute for the data that will be returned from the asmx service?

Comment: @mallows98: yes; if you use WCF, you need to write your client side proxy as if you're interfacign with a WCF service - the WCF client side proxy doesn't know or care that the service is an ASMX. All the things that are true for creating a WCF client for a WCF service apply here, too.

Comment: Thanks Mark & Abdul! Really do appreciate your feedback!